# Convert â€™ (’) for use in RSS URL

Tags: php, character-encoding, rss

I'm pulling out an image URL from a table in Wordpress.

The URL in the database looks like: `Power-behind-F1’s-winning-global-drive.jpg` field is UTF8 Unicode

When pulling it out to generate an RSS feed it comes out as `Power-behind-F1â€™s-winning-global-drive.jpg`

I can convert it to an html entity with `utf8_encode(htmlentities($url, ENT_QUOTES,'utf-8'))`which produces `Power-behind-F1&rsquo;s-winning-global-drive.jpg`. This however doesn't pass RSS validation:

[image]

I feel like I've tried every combination utf8_encode/htmlentities/urlencode/mb_convert_encoding and I've run out of ideas!

Comment: Contrary to common believe, `utf8_encode()` is not a magic function that solves Unicode issues. It merely converts *from ISO-8859-1* to UTF-8. Does your data use ISO-8859-1? How are you generating RSS exactly? (I suppose you're using some builtin Wordpress functionality but you don't say it explicitly).

Comment: The field encoding is UTF8 Unicode, I'm pulling these values out of the database manually and looping through to generate the RSS feed myself. Separate from Wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved so far with

```
$imageUrl = urlencode($theRawUrl);
$imageUrl = str_replace(array( '%2F', '%5C' ), "/", $imageUrl);
$imageUrl = str_replace("%3A", ":", $imageUrl);
```

Gross but it works...

Edit:

Another fix for me was:

`iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $content)`

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't code to see I can only share a few hints.

- UTF-8 is the de-facto standard nowadays. Legacy apps are the only reason to use any other encoding and it doesn't seem to be the case. Stick to UTF-8 and don't bother converting to any other encoding: it's pointless and it can only ruin your data.
- Escaping is always context-sensitive, not a universal truth. Don't apply random escaping functions to your data until it *seems* to work, unless you want to corrupt it.
- Don't generate XML with string concatenation: it doesn't have any advantage and it can eventually generate malformed XML (as it's the case). [Let PHP do the hard work for you](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). (Use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) if unsure.)